# C++ atioglxx.pdb not loaded error glBufferData OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, c++14, glm-math, opengl-3

i keep getting this error when trying to load an **OBJ** file into my project 
 
**atioglxx.pdb not loaded**

with the following exception 
 
**Exception thrown at 0x53A083FF (atioglxx.dll) in Reality.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0894F000.**

sometimes i get this error and sometimes i don't and have my model on the screen. So, i tried to debug the code and found that **glBufferData** function is what causes this error but couldn't figure out what is the problem with it.

Here the OBJ Loaded function

```
bool Mesh::LoadOBJ(std::string objFile) 
{
    std::vector<glm::vec3> position;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> UVs;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
    std::vector< float > vertices;
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
    std::unordered_map< std::string, unsigned int> isProcessed;

    std::ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open(objFile);
    if (!myFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error Openening OBJ file : " << objFile;
        return false; 
    }

    unsigned int cnt = 1;
    while (!myFile.eof())
    {
        std::string type;
        myFile >> type;
        float x, y, z;
        if (type == "v") {
            myFile >> x >> y >> z;

            glm::vec3 v(x, y, z); 
            position.push_back(v);
        }
        else if (type == "vt") {
            myFile >> x >> y;

            glm::vec2 v(x, y);
            UVs.push_back(v);
        }
        else if (type == "vn") {
            myFile >> x >> y >> z;
            glm::vec3 v(x, y, z);

            normals.push_back(v);
        }
        else if (type == "f") {
            std::string p1, p2, p3;
            std::vector<std::string> vertex(3);

            myFile >> p1;
            if (!isProcessed[p1]) {

                isProcessed[p1] = cnt;
                indices.push_back(cnt - 1);

                vertex[0] = "";
                vertex[1] = "";
                vertex[2] = "";

                int c = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < p1.size(); ++i) {
                    if (p1[i] == '/') {
                        ++c;
                        continue;
                    }
                    vertex[c] += p1[i]; 
                }

                if (vertex[0].size() > 0) {
                    int vertexIndex = std::stoi(vertex[0]);
                    --vertexIndex;
                    vertices.push_back(position[vertexIndex].x);
                    vertices.push_back(position[vertexIndex].y);
                    vertices.push_back(position[vertexIndex].z);
                }

                if (vertex[1].size() > 0) {
                    int UVsIndex = std::stoi(vertex[1]);
                    --UVsIndex;
                    vertices.push_back(UVs[UVsIndex].x);
                    vertices.push_back(UVs[UVsIndex].y);
                }

                if (vertex[2].size() > 0) {
                    int normalIndex = std::stoi(vertex[2]);
                    --normalIndex;
                    vertices.push_back(normals[normalIndex].x);
                    vertices.push_back(normals[normalIndex].y);
                    vertices.push_back(normals[normalIndex].z);
                }

                ++cnt;

            }
            else {
                indices.push_back(isProcessed[p1] - 1);
            }

            myFile >> p2;
            if (!isProcessed[p2]) {

                isProcessed[p2] = cnt;
                indices.push_back(cnt - 1);

                vertex[0] = "";
                vertex[1] = "";
                vertex[2] = "";

                int c = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < p2.size(); ++i) {
                    if (p2[i] == '/') {
                        ++c;
                        continue;
                    }
                    vertex[c] += p2[i];
                }

                if (vertex[0].size() > 0) {
                    int vertexIndex = std::stoi(vertex[0]);
                    --vertexIndex;
                    vertices.push_back(position[vertexIndex].x);
                    vertices.push_back(position[vertexIndex].y);
                    vertices.push_back(position[vertexIndex].z);
                }

                if (vertex[1].size() > 0) {
                    int UVsIndex = std::stoi(vertex[1]);
                    --UVsIndex;
                    vertices.push_back(UVs[UVsIndex].x);
                    vertices.push_back(UVs[UVsIndex].y);
                }

                if (vertex[2].size() > 0) {
                    int normalIndex = std::stoi(vertex[2]);
                    --normalIndex;
                    vertices.push_back(normals[normalIndex].x);
                    vertices.push_back(normals[normalIndex].y);
                    vertices.push_back(normals[normalIndex].z);
                }

                ++cnt;

            }
            else {
                indices.push_back(isProcessed[p2] - 1);
            }

            myFile >> p3;
            if (!isProcessed[p3]) {

                isProcessed[p3] = cnt;
                indices.push_back(cnt - 1);

                vertex[0] = "";
                vertex[1] = "";
                vertex[2] = "";

                int c = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < p3.size(); ++i) {
                    if (p3[i] == '/') {
                        ++c;
                        continue;
                    }
                    vertex[c] += p3[i];
                }

                if (vertex[0].size() > 0) {
                    int vertexIndex = std::stoi(vertex[0]);
                    --vertexIndex;
                    vertices.push_back(position[vertexIndex].x);
                    vertices.push_back(position[vertexIndex].y);
                    vertices.push_back(position[vertexIndex].z);
                }

                if (vertex[1].size() > 0) {
                    int UVsIndex = std::stoi(vertex[1]);
                    --UVsIndex;
                    vertices.push_back(UVs[UVsIndex].x);
                    vertices.push_back(UVs[UVsIndex].y);
                }

                if (vertex[2].size() > 0) {
                    int normalIndex = std::stoi(vertex[2]);
                    --normalIndex;
                    vertices.push_back(normals[normalIndex].x);
                    vertices.push_back(normals[normalIndex].y);
                    vertices.push_back(normals[normalIndex].z);
                }

                ++cnt;

            }
            else {
                indices.push_back(isProcessed[p3] - 1);
            }
        }

    mVAO = new VertexArrayObject(vertices , vertices.size() , indices , static_cast<unsigned int>(indices.size())); 
    myFile.close();
    return true ;
```

and here is the constructor of my **VertexArray** class

```
VertexArrayObject::VertexArrayObject(std::vector<float>& vertices, int VBOsize, std::vector<unsigned int>& indecies, unsigned int EBOsize):
    EBOsize(EBOsize)
{

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mVAOiD);
    glBindVertexArray(mVAOiD);

    glGenBuffers(1, &mVBOiD);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBOiD);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * VBOsize * sizeof(float) , &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &mEBOiD);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mEBOiD);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBOsize * sizeof(unsigned int), &indecies[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), reinterpret_cast<void*>(sizeof(float) * 3));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), reinterpret_cast<void*>(sizeof(float) * 5));
}
```

and this is the OBJ file for the model i'm trying to render
[Rock.obj](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1fdkDMmvVZ0bXFiMbNqqxczCeLXz-8Iuh&export=download)

**Note**
this is my first question on stackoverflow so please take it easy on me.

Comment: ***atioglxx.pdb not loaded*** is not a bug or problem. Your graphics driver did not provide debugging symbols to allow you to step into the implementation of your GPU drivers. Even if this was available you should not need or want that. It's not like you are going to want to debug AMD's code for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation of the buffer size in bytes is wrong. `verizes.size()` is not the number of vertex attribute, it is the number of `float` elements in the `std::vector`.

You pass `vertices.size()` to the argument `VBOsize` of `VertexArrayObject`s constructor:

> ```cpp
> mVAO = new VertexArrayObject(vertices , vertices.size(), indices ,static_cast<unsigned int>(indices.size()));
> ```

In the constructor `VBOsize` is multiplied by 8:

> ```cpp
> VertexArrayObject::VertexArrayObject(std::vector<float>& vertices, int VBOsize, std::vector<unsigned int>& indecies, unsigned int EBOsize)
>    :EBOsize(EBOsize)
> {
>    // [...]
>
>    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * VBOsize * sizeof(float) , &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
>    // [...]
> ```

If `VBOsize` is the number of vertices, then you have to divide `vertices.size()` by 8:

<s>`mVAO = new VertexArrayObject(vertices, vertices.size() , indices , static_cast<unsigned int>(indices.size()));`</s>

```cpp
mVAO = new VertexArrayObject(vertices, vertices.size() / 8, indices, static_cast<unsigned int>(indices.size()));
```

Anyway, I recommend to change the computation of the buffer size:

<s>`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * VBOsize * sizeof(float) , &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);`</s>

```cpp
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```